# What does it mean to buy a top level domain(TLD)?

Tags: networking, web, dns, tld

Recently I read news about Google bought .app, Amazon bought .buy, what does it mean? They own every domain name followed by .app? I can only register with google if I want to have blahblah.app, and they can say no even if no one is using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain/DNS works with "zones". The "top level zone" in this case being "app". Above that there is only anymore ICANN/IANA.

They can do what ever they like with the zone (according to the rules & regulations made by ICANN/IANA) - they do not have to sell domains within their zone.

Selling domains as what .COM (verisign) does is purely due to that being their business model.
Google or Amazon on the other hand might find other value in owning a TLD/Zone and might rather use it to promote/canonicalize their own projects instead of selling sub-zones.

Comment: Well, in this case, buying a top level domain seems a very good deal.